# Open a new full-size window in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android

We have a responsive web app designed to run on all of the latest various desktop and mobile browsers. We are encountering a problem with the latest Android default browser (*Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 4.4*) when opening a new window using `window.open()`. The browser appears to treat any such window as a "pop-up" window (or "dialog" window, or "subwindow"). This is a problem if that window in turn tries to open another window using `window.open()`, in which case the browser gives the message:

```
Pop-up already open
Only one pop-up can be open at a time
```

This behavior was not present in previous (4.3) browser versions, and we don't see this problem on other browser platforms.

This is a particularly sticky problem because the second "pop-up" window is needed to log the user in via his Facebook/Google/etc account.

I did some research and tried adding `fullscreen=yes` and `dialog=no` to the [features parameter](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features) of the `window.open()` call, but these had no effect. I also briefly got it to work by removing the `width=nnn` and `height=nnn` feature settings (which allows the browser to assume the full available screen size for the new window), but this mysteriously stopped working after a day or two, and in fact, I'm still seeing inconsistent results on [BrowserStack](http://BrowserStack.com).

The exact feature string is:

```
"location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no"
```

with various permutations/omissions of `fullscreen`, `dialog`, `width`, and `height` settings.

Anyone know how to *consistently* force the creation of a full-screen non-pop-up window on this device? Is it possible that this is only a BrowserStack problem? (For obvious reasons, we cannot configure or change the user's browsers, since we have thousands of users managing their own devices.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing various combinations of features, the solution we chose was to simply omit all features (i.e., providing an empty features string) when opening the new window.

```
var w = window.open(url, "foo", "");    // Empty 3rd param
```

This appears to work for Android (4.4).